# Banner not appearing on page

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-deployment

So, what I want is when I am scrolling down through my website, and when I reach a certain page (in this case it is the `contact` page), I want the end banner (more details are below) to appear right then at the bottom right of the website. It basically says a goodbye message, and you have the choice to close the end banner or keep it open.

Example:

```js
(function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    var banner1;
    banner1 = document.querySelector('.exponea-banner1');
    banner1.classList.add('exponea-in1');
    return banner1.querySelector('.exponea-close1').addEventListener('click', function() {
      return banner1.classList.remove('exponea-in1');
    });
  });

}).call(this);
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500");
html,
body1 {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.exponea-banner1 {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #2e364d;
  color: #ebeef7;
  padding: 30px 80px 30px 35px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 30px rgba(116, 119, 176, 0.3);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
.exponea-banner1.exponea-in1 {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}
.exponea-banner1 .exponea-close1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 300;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.75;
}
.exponea-banner1 .exponea-label1 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  opacity: 0.75;
}
.exponea-banner1 .exponea-text1 {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.exponea-banner1 .exponea-count1 {
  font-weight: 500;
}
.exponea-banner1 .exponea-label1 {
  text-align: left;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  opacity: 0.75;
}
.exponea-banner1,
.exponea-close1,
.exponea-text1,
.exponea-label1,
.exponea-label21 {
    z-index: 10;
}

<! ------- CSS of introduction banner------------------ --> 
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500");
html,
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.exponea-banner {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #2e364d;
  color: #ebeef7;
  padding: 30px 80px 30px 35px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 30px rgba(116, 119, 176, 0.3);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
.exponea-banner.exponea-in {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}
.exponea-banner .exponea-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 300;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.75;
}
.exponea-banner .exponea-label {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  opacity: 0.75;
}
.exponea-banner .exponea-text {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.exponea-banner .exponea-count {
  font-weight: 500;
}
.exponea-banner .exponea-label {
  text-align: left;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  opacity: 0.75;
}
.exponea-banner,
.exponea-close,
.exponea-text,
.exponea-label,
.exponea-label2 {
    z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<section>
INTRODUCTION</section>
<section>
<br>
<body>
  <script>
    (function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    var banner;
    banner = document.querySelector('.exponea-banner');
    banner.classList.add('exponea-in');
    return banner.querySelector('.exponea-close').addEventListener('click', function() {
      return banner.classList.remove('exponea-in');
    });
  });

}).call(this);
    </script>
  <div class="exponea-banner">
  <div class="exponea-close">
    &times;
  </div>
  <div class="exponea-text">
    Hi there! Thanks for stumbling upon my website!
  </div>
  <div class="exponea-label">
    - Hussain Omer
  </div>
</div>
Random stuff here
</section>
<section>
Random stuff here
</section>
<section>
Random stuff here
</section>
<section>
Random stuff here
</section>
<section>
Random stuff here
</section>
<section>
Random stuff here
</section>
<section>
Random stuff here
</section>
<section>
Random stuff here
</section>
<section>
Random stuff here
</section>
<section>
Random stuff here
</section>
<section>
Random stuff here
</section>
<section>
Random stuff here
</section>
<section>
Random stuff here
</section>
<section>
Random stuff here
</section>
<section>
Random stuff here
</section>
<section>
Random stuff here
</section>
<section>
Random stuff here
</section>
<section>
Random stuff here
</section>
<section>
Random stuff here
</section>
<section>
Random stuff here
</section>
<section>
Random stuff here
</section>
<section>
Random stuff here
</section>
<section>
Random stuff here
</section>
<section>
Random stuff here
</section>
<section>
Random stuff here
</section>
<section>
Random stuff here
</section>
<section>
Random stuff here
</section>
<section>
Random stuff here
</section>
<section>
Random stuff here
</section>
<section>
Random stuff here
</section>
<section>
Random stuff here
</section>
<section>
Random stuff here
</section>
<section>
Random stuff here
</section>
<section>
Random stuff here
</section>
<section>
Random stuff here
</section>
<section>
Random stuff here
</section>
<section>
Random stuff here
</section>
<section>
Random stuff here
</section>
<section>
Random stuff here
</section>
<section>
<h2> contact section </h2>
<!-- ======= Contact Section ======= --> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bannerclose.css">
    <body>
  <div class="exponea-banner1">
  <div class="exponea-close1">
    &times;
  </div>
  <div class="exponea-text1">
    Thanks for visiting! &#58398;
  </div>
    </div>
  <div class="exponea-label1">
    - Hussain Omer
  </div>
</div>
```

So I provided an example, I already have the start banner in my website included, like the introduction banner works fine and everything. The end banner, or the banner that  I want to appear once I scroll down to the contact section is not quite working.

How would I make it so that when the person scrolls down to the contact section, the banner **only then** appears near the bottom of the page? Because right now it's appearing all over the website but I want the end banner (which has the "thanks for visiting" message) to appear only after the contact section.

Please help, its been 2 days and I still couldn't figure out a way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I tell if a DOM element is visible in the current viewport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-can-i-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport)

Comment: I think you are looking for JS's IntersectionObserver [link]https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API but you also need to review your use of requestAnimationFrame - it gets called on load I'm not sure why and its callback function makes the Thanks section displayed immediately.

Comment: @sidekick12 Do you want something like this: https://stackoverflow-sidekick12.netlify.app/

Comment: Yes, could I see the code? @ManasKhandelwal

Comment: @sidekick12 I have added the answer. Sorry, I just forgot to add the answer. Thank you for reminding me.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to detect, If the user has reached the end of the page and to enable closing by clicking on the close icon:

```
const toast = document.getElementById("toast");
const toastClose = document.getElementById("toastClose");
window.onscroll = function (b) {
  if (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
    toast.classList.add("open");
  }
};
toastClose.addEventListener("click", function () {
  toast.classList.remove("open");
});
```

---

Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/ExgdzWd

---

Live link: https://stackoverflow-sidekick12.netlify.app/